# Display alerts when clicked on JavaFX

Tags: java, button, javafx

I have a button called woodcuttingButton on my JavaFX program, and when it is clicked, it will alert the player to choose which tree they would like to cut.

Unfortunately, when the button is clicked, nothing happens.

```
woodcuttingButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            alert.setTitle("Woodcutting");
            alert.setHeaderText("What tree would you like to cut?");
            alert.setContentText("Choose your option.");

            ButtonType buttonTypeOak = new ButtonType("Oak");
            ButtonType buttonTypeWillow = new ButtonType("Willow");
            ButtonType buttonTypeMaple = new ButtonType("Maple");
            ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);

            alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOak, buttonTypeWillow, buttonTypeMaple, buttonTypeCancel);
        });
```

Am I implementing the alert incorrectly?

Comment: Looks like `runescape` to me lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implemented correctly (at least what youve shown) but you need to show the dialog

```
alert.showAndWait();
```